# Prevent tech tree overview from closing when clicking a tech

Tags: civilization-5, mods, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I'm using Enhanced User Interface mod for Civilization 5 Brave New World and I really love it. There's one problem I have with it though; I like to click around on the tech tree when deciding what to research. Enhanced User Interface however closes the tech overview when you click a tech. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe happens when you click on the Blue color Bulb at the bottom right corner when it comes up to "Choose Research".

If you don't click that but instead click the smaller Blue Bulb in the upper left corner where your science is, that will get you to the Tech Tree and you can click away and it will not close the tech overview until you choose to close it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That sounds plausible! I'm gonna give this a try as soon as possible.